# Variation of Knapsack Problem: adding Low bounder

Tags: knapsack-problem

Classic variation of 0/1 Knapsack Problem: Only I have to specify low bounder. It means I have to find maximum value and make sure that total weight is equal or higher than some given value but not higher than capacity of a Knapsack. Basically, determine that the solution is between 2 boundries.

I have already code 0/1 Knapsack problem with dynamic programming. And I could test it for low bounder. Something like if the solution is lower than low bounder find second best solution for knapsack and so on. But I believe there is a better way.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any language requirement?

Comment: This is for multihead weigher which is a industry machine. So im writing PLC program using ST language. Which is similar to Pascal. 

To answer you question I have to understand the concept of a solution. So I really do not care about the language. I like Python or C,C++ or if you know ST language it would be perfect :)